# Typing lists in function arguments in Dart

Tags: dart, types

It's great that Dart allows us to type arguments for functions:

```dart
void createPerson(String name, int age, sayHey: Function) {
  /* Create */
}
```

But what if the argument should be a list of said type. I.e:

```dart
void createPeople(List<?> peopleConfigs) {
  /* Create multiple */
}
```

What's the best way to type `peopleConfigs` here? And will tooling like code hint/completion still work when passing the arguments?

I know I can just use `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` but I wonder if there's a more type-safe way that would throw compile-time errors if keys were used that shouldn't be.

I'm coming from TypeScript where this is pretty straight forward:

```js
createPeople(peopleConfigs: {name: string, age: number, sayHey: () => void}[]): void {
  /* Create multiple */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your `peopleConfigs` to hold some functions with defined type signature:

You can use `typedef` for this:

```dart
typedef PersonConfig = void Function(
  String name,
  int age,
  Function sayHey,
);

//ok function
void create1(String name, int age, Function sayHey) {}

//not ok function
void create2(String name, double age, Function sayHey) {}

void createPeople(List<PersonConfig> peopleConfigs) {
  //some logic
}

void main() {
  createPeople(<PersonConfig>[
    create1, //<--- ok
    (String name, int age, Function sayHey) {}, //<--- ok
    create2, // <--- error
  ]);
}
```

If you want your `peopleConfigs` to hold class instances:

```dart
class PersonConfig {
  final String? name;
  final int? age;
  final Function? sayHey;

  PersonConfig({
    this.name,
    this.age,
    this.sayHey,
  });
}

void createPeople(List<PersonConfig> peopleConfigs) {
  //some logic
}

void main() {
  createPeople(<PersonConfig>[
    PersonConfig(name: "", age: 0, sayHey: () => "hi"),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. It looks like the list contains functions, not objects/maps?

Comment: I updated my answer. The first example is about how to use a function type signature in lists. The second example is about how to create a typed object. Maybe I didn't understand your question... @shennan

Comment: Ok, I see. So you would recommend creating a list of instantiated classes as arguments in order to fulfil this requirement? I guess, coming from JavaScript, I'm used to not needing to add the boilerplate of class instantiation as you can pass object literals around freely as arguments to functions; and TypeScript adds further type-checking on those objects. But if this is the best way to do this in Dart then so be it!

Comment: Yes, in Dart, you have to declare a class for this...

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type, then you can define a list of said type as a parameter:

```
class Parameters {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  final Function sayHey;
  
  Parameters({required this.name, required this.age, required this.sayHey});
}

void someFunction(List<Parameters> parameters) {
  print(parameters);
}

void main() {
  someFunction([
    Parameters(name: "Joe", age: 21, sayHey: () => print("hi") ),
    Parameters(name: "Suzi", age: 24, sayHey: () => print("hello") ),
  ]);
}
```